# How to avoid \qty conflict with physics and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, incompatibility, physics

I am trying to use both the `physics` and `siunitx` packages, which both have a definition for the command `\qty`. I want to ignore the one from `physics` and use only that from `siunitx`. This is my minimum non working example, what I would like to see instead of "{10}" is "10 m."

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

I want to express a quantity: \qty{10}{\meter}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Many macros in the `physics` package are either provided by other packages as well or are so poorly implemented that users are often better off providing their own macro definitions instead of relying on those of the `physics` package. Please tell us which macros of the `physics` package you tend to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the originally accepted answer seems to have gone obsolete, Joseph suggests this alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\begin{document}

I want to express a quantity: \qty{10}{\meter}.

\end{document}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You need to load `siunitx` first, save a copy of the defined `\qty` and, once `physics` is loaded, restore the original meaning assigned to `\qty` by `siunitx`.

The `siunitx` developer @Joseph Wright adds useful comments below the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\svqty}{\qty}
\usepackage{physics}
\LetLtxMacro{\qty}{\svqty}

\begin{document}

I want to express a quantity: \qty{10}{\meter}.

\end{document}
```

or, more simply

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\let\svqty\qty
\usepackage{physics}
\let\qty\svqty

\begin{document}

I want to express a quantity: \qty{10}{\meter}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) As `siuntix` always provides `\SI`, you don't need to save and restore, just `\let\qty\SI` (although I'd be tempted to use `\RenewCommandCopy`); 2) As `physics` predates `siunitx` using `\qty`, the current approach is 'by design' (`physics` 'owns' `\qty` in that sense) - worth at least mentioning

Comment: This solution does not work anymore :(

Comment: @RubemPacelli I have no problem compiling either of the given solutions using up-to-date packages.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes well, copying and pasting both solutions on overleaf did not work...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [take a look](https://i.ibb.co/LZsb67J/image.png)

Comment: @JosephWright I downloaded the latest `siunitx` and `physics` packages and my MWEs above still compile.  Rubem says they don't compile on overleaf.  Do you know if I am out of phase or is Overleaf/Rubem?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ruben is right: you'll want `\NewCommandCopy` to make this work here, or as I suggest in the docs use `\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Unfortunately, I do not know :(